# How to prevent conflicts between css rules

Tags: css, styles, conflict

What is the best strategy for creating css selectors for html widgets. Those selectors should not be in conflict with child elements nor with possible general selectors.

```
/* this item class it is already done, has no relation with my widgets´ items
  and i can´t modify it*/        
   .item { color:red; }    

   .my-first-widget{...}
   .my-first-widget .item { color: blue; font-size:16px;}

   .my-second-widget{...} 
   .my-second-widget .item { font-size:14px;}
```

Problems with the code above:

1. If I insert my-second-widget inside a my-first-widget (but not within a my-first-widget .item), the items from my-second-widget   will be blue (I want them to inherit color from it´s parent).
2. I insert my-second-widget inside a project with a  rule defined as .item , the items from my-second-widget will be red (I want them to inherit color from it´s parent; not from the unrelated general item´s class).

which is the best solution for styling exportable widgets?

**Solution 1** (use parent class a prefix)

```
   .my-first-widget{...}
   .my-first-widget-item { color: blue; font-size:16px;}

   .my-second-widget{} 
   .my-second-widget-item { font-size:14px;}
```

**Solution 2** (use child selectors)

```
   .my-first-widget{...}
   .my-first-widget > .item { color: blue; font-size:16px;}

   .my-second-widget{ color: black;} 
   .my-second-widget > .item { font-size:14px;}
```

With the solution2 i still have a conflict with the general .item selector...

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the following might work for you.

If this is your HTML:

```
<div class="project">
    <div class="item">item outside widget</div>
    <div class="my-second-widget"><span class="item">item</span></div>
</div>
```

try this CSS:

```css
.item {
    color:red;
}
.my-first-widget {
}
.my-first-widget .item {
    color: blue;
    font-size:16px;
}
.my-second-widget {
}
.my-second-widget .item {
    color: inherit;
    font-size:14px;
}

.project {
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/3eLpU/

Set `color: inherit` on `.my-second-widget .item`, which will force the nested `.item` to inherit the color value from `.my-second-widget` (if it is set), or the color value of `.project` (if it is set) or ultimately, the body (set or default value).

If the top level `.item` rule is present, it will be applied outside of `.my-second-widget`.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works but what should i do to prevent the effect of other rules in the general .item class like border, background,...? Writting inherit for all of them doesnt seem a good thing

Comment: I am afraid that there is no magic bullet for this problem.  You need to keep the widget CSS rules as self-contained as possible, which means that you will need to specify every property that is critical to you design, and make sure that properties like `float: none`, `position: static` and so on are explicitly set.  You cannot assume anything about what might be in an external 3rd party style sheet.  In fact, some widgets even go so far as to use inline-styles to make sure that you can't clobber the widget layout (example, Constant Contact email sign-up).

Comment: What do you think about the solution 1 described in the opening post? I think that this solution in combination with yours(specify all criticals properties) for tag selectors like ".my-widget a" can be a good strategy

Comment: When I think about it, the source of the problem is due to identical class names being defined in multiple style sheets.  Creating unique names would like `.my-unique-tag-item` would do the trick.  The trick is to make sure all the tags have a corresponding CSS rule with a selector of high enough specificity, for example. `.my-unique-tag-container .my-unique-header a` and so on.